# If condition won't work Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula and it doesn't work: `=IF(A1="oui","1",if(A1="non","0",""))`

I asked a couple of friends to test it, and oddly, it works fine with them!

What did I do wrong? And how do I fix it?

Comment: How does it not work? What does it output?

Comment: Try to use a semi-colon (`;`)

Comment: @pnuts Sorry chief! Post deleted from the other website!
What do you mean by sheet's Locale?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra the semi-colon `;` doesn't work.

Comment: @pnuts if I go to `File, Spreadsheet settings` it gives me `Locale : France`, `Time zone : London` and `Recalculation : On change`
I just changed them to `Locale : United States`, `Time zone : GMT` and now it is working. Thanks!
Does this mean that the commands don't work for French settings?

Comment: Oh I see, that's because I got it wrong, I thought I had to put `;` in the end of the instruction not as a delimiter.
Now I tried it, it works!
Thanks for your help!